# Problem with to do list. How Can I get back my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

It's my first to do app with filter method. All of these functions works fine, but I have problem when I'm try search something in second input, when I search for one element I lose the rest of the array. How Can I fix that xD ?

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const add = document.querySelector('.addNew')
const clear = document.querySelector('.clear')
const div = document.querySelector('.container')
const search = document.querySelector('.search')

let words = [];
const newTask = () => {             // add new task
    if(input.value === '') return;
    const li = document.createElement('li')
    const pe = document.createElement('p')
   const btnsComplete = document.createElement('button')
    const btnDelete = document.createElement('button')
    div.appendChild(li)
    li.appendChild(pe)
    li.appendChild(btnsComplete)
    li.appendChild(btnDelete)
    pe.textContent = input.value
    btnsComplete.textContent = 'Done'
    btnDelete.textContent = 'Cancel'
    input.value = '';
    
    words.push(li)
    btnsComplete.addEventListener('click',function(e){   // complete
        pe.classList.toggle('line')   
        })
    btnDelete.addEventListener('click',function(e){       //cancel
        e.target.parentNode.remove()
        words.pop(e.target)
        document.querySelector('.info').textContent = `Twoja lista składa się z ${words.length} elementów`
    })
document.querySelector('.info').textContent = `Twoja lista składa się z ${words.length} elementów`
    

}
const clearing =() => {             //remove all todos
    div.innerHTML = ''
    words.length = 0
    document.querySelector('.info').textContent = `Twoja lista składa się z ${words.length} elementów`
}


const searchTask = (e) => {        //search task
    const searchText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    words = words.filter(li => li.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchText))
    div.textContent =''
    words.forEach(li => div.appendChild(li))
  
}

search.addEventListener('input', searchTask)

clear.addEventListener('click', clearing)
add.addEventListener('click', newTask)
```

Comment: Change the variable that is getting the filtered results to something like `results = words.filter` then loop that in the forEach in the searchTask function

Comment: dont assign the result of filter to  words but to a different locally defined variable instead

Comment: thanks both of you <3 now it's work